# Performing an insert query into a loop from an select results

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, for-loop, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to perform an insert query into a loop from a select results.
The problem is when I want to retrieve only one result from a select query that works correctly
but when the select query retrieve more than one result that doesn't work.

Is there an issue with the GROUP_CONCAT function ? How can I do in order fix the issue ?

I let you the code snippet here :

```
BEGIN

    SELECT idJour INTO @idJour FROM `jour` WHERE JourSemaine = DayWeek;
    
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(idTrancheH) AS result FROM tranchehoraire WHERE TrancheH BETWEEN heureDebut AND heureFin;
  
    loop_label : loop
    
        INSERT INTO `horaire` (`idEmployé`, `idJour`, `idTrancheH`) VALUES
        (idEmployee,@idJour, @idTrancheH);

    SET  heureDebut = ADDTIME(heureDebut ,'0:30:00.00');

        IF  heureDebut <= TIME(heureFin) THEN 
            ITERATE  loop_label;
        ELSE
                LEAVE  loop_label;
        END  IF;
        
    END LOOP;
   RETURN heureDebut;
END
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the code should be doing would be quite helpful.  I doubt a loop is really needed for what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, I let you the explanation : I need to perform a function that fill the table 'Horaire'. This function needs to take in arguments idEmploye, nameofDay, startTime (datedebut) and endTime (dateFin). It will fill the table 'Horaire' with all the required records for this employee, this day and all the time between the started time and end time. For instance, 09:00:00 startTime and 12:00:00 endTime I need to add 09:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00.  Is it more clear now ?